# VxFS on both Solaris and RHEL?

Tags: filesystems, file-sharing, rhel5, rhel6, veritas

I'd like to know if VxFS could be used in order to share a volume ( on a SAN mounted using FC) between a RHEL (5 or 6) and Solaris (11) host ?

What I'm trying to achive is to shared a volume (from a SAN) across a grid of hosts running Solaris and RHEL.

According to Symantec VxFS (CFS version) can perform the share and concurrent access with high perfs.

Now the question is can it work on a heterogen setup with both Solaris (sparc) and Linux (x86).

Thanks for any pointers,

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do. You really only ever present block-level storage to two separate hosts in a cluster scenerio. If you just want to share the volume between the two, you need some sort of NAS functionality like CIFS or NFS and not FC.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to share a storage volume (from a SAN) across a grid of hosts running Solaris and RHEL.According to Symantec VxFS (CFS version) can perform the share and concurrent access with high perfs. Now the question is can it work on a heterogen setup with both solaris and linux. Otherwise NFS is still an option I guess.

Comment: @devlearn please provide the informations within the question. Just edit it.

Comment: desc included in the topic

Answer (score 1):

I've received three answers from Veritas/Symantec consultants and the final word is that VxCFS cannot serve the same volume on computers with different CPU architectures.

So either all the nodes are X86 or Sparc but mixed environment is not supported.

So the use case Solaris Sparc/RHEL is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

It can yes, in fact that's exactly what it's for.

Comment: Hi, means that VxCVS supports the concurrent access from both OS ? Do you by any chance have a link to a symantec page (or sheet) where this is stated ?